Middleware on Inertia::render() response
I'm trying to catch the response in the middleware that I've created, sent by the method Inertia::render().
I'm trying to do that because i want to create the Resource class with all the possible field, and also the view file.
Only after the response is ready to be sent, catch it in the middleware, filter it to unset some useless field (because the user doesn't want to see it), add a parameter with the column that need to be shown and finally send it.
use \Inertia\Response as InertiaResponse;

class SellerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(): InertiaResponse
    {
        $query = Seller::with(['person', 'customers'])->get();

        $response = Inertia::render('Seller/Index', [
            'sellers' => SellerResource::collection($query),
        ]);

        //`dd($response)`;
        return $response;
    }
....
}

If I uncomment dd($response), the object response is what I expect, an \Inertia\Response.
This is the middleware that I've created:
class FilterResourceFields
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($response instanceof InertiaResponse) 
        {
            // Obtained data passed by inertia
            // Check if there are data in the response
            // get ModelClass Usa il modello dinamico dalla risposta
            // get user
            // get visible field for the user
            // filter data
            // edit props send by inertia
            // return
        }

        return $response;
    }
}

My route in web.php is:
Route::get('/sellers', [SellerController::class, 'index'])->name('sellers.index')->middleware('filter.resource');

and in the kernel.php file i've added the FilterResourceFields::class in
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\FilterResourceFields::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
            \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\AddLinkHeadersForPreloadedAssets::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'filter.resource' => \App\Http\Middleware\FilterResourceFields::class,
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];

I tried to edit the position in the array in kernel.php to see if there was some priority.
